# Can't add a js snippet from google trends into an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

Am trying to add a js script to make a google trends show up on an html page. i gradbed the embed code straight from the first graphic at http://goo.gl/4C92vk and turned it into the following, which doesn't work

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=en-US&q=chicago+marathon&cmpt=q&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=330"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

any thoughts? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<iframe scrolling="no" style="border:none;" width="250" height="413" src="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/widget?pn=p1&amp;tn=10&amp;h=413"></iframe>');
</script>
</div>
</body>
```